# What is the type hint for a method?

Tags: python, methods, python-typing

What is the right type hint for a `method`? There is `typing.Callable`, but I'm looking for a **method** type hint, and `typing.Callable[[Self, ...], ...]` is not working.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```py
class _Object:
    """An empty object for method type."""

    def method(self) -> None:
        """
        A method.

        :return None: Nothing.
        """
        return None


MethodType: Type = type(_Object().method)
```

MethodType is a *type* and not a *type alias*. Which type should I use then? I'm using Python 3.11.

Comment: Sorry, it was an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) case. I'm going to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType) would be the annotation to use for "specifically a method object", but most of the time, `typing.Callable` will be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

`Callable` applies to anything that is `callable` (functions, methods, classes, ...).

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeAlias  # TypeAlias available thru typing-extensions for Python <= 3.9


class MyBase:

    def method(self, i: int, j: int) -> int:
        return i + j


MethodType: TypeAlias = Callable[[MyBase, int, int], int]
a: MethodType = MyBase.method  # if you want to use a TypeAlias

b: Callable[[MyBase, int, int], int] = MyBase.method  # self must provided explicitly

my_base = MyBase()
c: Callable[[int, int], int] = my_base.method  # self is provided implicitly
```

As an extension of this, if you want to type methods generically i.e. for the methods of subclasses of a base class, you can use a `TypeVar`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=MyBase)  # T is either an instance of MyBase or a subclass of MyBase


class MyDerived(MyBase):
    ...


def my_decorator(my_function: Callable[[MyBase, int, int], int]) -> Callable[[MyBase, int, int], int]:
    return my_function


def my_generic_decorator(my_function: Callable[[T, int, int], int]) -> Callable[[T, int, int], int]:
    return my_function


my_decorator(MyDerived.method)  # Parameter 1: type "MyBase" cannot be assigned to type "MyDerived"
my_generic_decorator(MyDerived.method)  # OK
```